# Monitor on-Premises website using Azure Application Insight

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I am trying to monitor an on-Premises website (not public) using Azure Application Insight. I created a web test which pings the on-premise web site. However the web test is failing with the following error:

```
System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server --->
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 9.9.9.9:999 at 
System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebStress.WebTestTransaction.ResponseReceived(IAsyncResult result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you can connect to the URL for the Application Insights Availability Web Test in a browser. If the URL can't be reached from the Internet, then the Application Insights Web Test will not work. Application Insights needs to be able to hit the URL you specify across the Internet, so any internal only accessible addresses will not work.

Comment: Thanks Chris for your reply, URL cant be reached as this is not public. I was wondering if there is any similar functionality like Hybrid Connection for Application Insights by which we can access on premise resources?

Answer (score 0):

For your specific requirement you can add an intermediate layer of web service in your DMZ or another machine in your environment which has access to Azure public resources as well as the internal resources. From this web service simply invoke the application insights code with custom data for each different page request or events. Then from your app try invoking this web service instead.

Also as your resource is internal without access to Azure App Insights, you should run web tests internally instead of online version.

This is not an ideal solution but should work in your situation.

Comment: Thanks Aman for sharing solution, I used web job and hybrid connection manager to connect to on-premise website.